# Bitwise operations in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

Could someone help me how to perform bitwise  `AND` operations on two tensors in Pytorch 1.4?

Apparently I could only find `NOT` and `XOR` operations in official [document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see them in the docs, but it looks like `&`, `|`, `__and__`, `__or__`, `__xor__`, etc are bit-wise:

```
>>> torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).__xor__(torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1]))
tensor([0, 3, 2, 5])
>>> torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]) | torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1])
tensor([1, 3, 3, 5])
>>> torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]) & torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1])
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0])
>>> torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).__and__(torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1]))
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1556

Answer (score 0):

Check this. There is no bitwise and/or operation for tensors in Torch. There are element-wise operations implemented in Torch, but not bite-wise ones.

However, if you could convert each bit as a separate Tensor dimension, you can use element-wise operation.

For an example,

```
a = torch.Tensor{0,1,1,0}
b = torch.Tensor{0,1,0,1}

torch.cmul(a,b):eq(1)
0
1
0
0
[torch.ByteTensor of size 4]

torch.add(a,b):ge(1)
0
1
1
1
[torch.ByteTensor of size 4]
```

Hope this will help you.